# How to make a custom MultiAutoCompleteTextView inside a Material TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, material-ui, android-custom-view, android-textinputlayout, multiautocompletetextview

I want to customize a `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`, which will be placed inside a `TextInputLayout` in order to use Material, for the sake of reusability and updatability to the underlying code.

I have yet to start and I already have problems with it though.

[Graphic demostration of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtlHD.png)

As you can see, the first `TextInputLayout` is completely wrong.
They both have the exact same structure and attributes, the only different thing is the custom view.
It is basically an empty class that extends `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`.

Below is the xml and the custom view class.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/custom_view"
        style="@style/Theme.CustomViews.MorphInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/standard_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

        <com.scitalys.customViews.ui.main.MorphInputText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/standard_view"
        style="@style/Theme.CustomViews.MorphInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/custom_view">

        <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

```
class MorphInputText @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        this.threshold = 1
        val textWatcher = MorphInputTextWatcher
        this.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `defStyleAttr` in the constructor:

```
class MorphInputText @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.autoCompleteTextViewStyle
) : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr){

}
```